# Generating a REST API in Hyperledger Composer error

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm following the tutorial to generate REST API whith [Digital Land Title Network](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/getting-started-rest-api.html) example. But I get the following error:

```
To restart the REST server using the same options, issue the following command:
   composer-rest-server -p defaultProfile -n digitalproperty-network -i WebAppAdmin -s DJY27pEnl16d -N always

Discovering types from business network definition ...
Connection fails: Error: {"created":"@1494321356.313456565","description":"Failed parsing HTTP/2","file":"../src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.c","file_line":2022,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1494321356.313436962","description":"Expected SETTINGS frame as the first frame, got frame type 80","file":"../src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/parsing.c","file_line":479}{"created":"@1494321356.313450563","description":"Trying to connect an http1.x server","file":"../src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.c","file_line":1995,"http_status":400}]}
It will be retried for the next request.
{ Error: {"created":"@1494321356.313456565","description":"Failed parsing HTTP/2","file":"../src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.c","file_line":2022,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1494321356.313436962","description":"Expected SETTINGS frame as the first frame, got frame type 80","file":"../src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/parsing.c","file_line":479}{"created":"@1494321356.313450563","description":"Trying to connect an http1.x server","file":"../src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.c","file_line":1995,"http_status":400}]}
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:417:17 code: 14, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }
```

It happent too when deploy a new network definition ...it seems that can`t comunicate with Hyperledger Fabric. But Fabric its running

```
calmadmin@localhost:~/composer-sample-applications-hlfv1/packages/getting-started$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
04d28aa6dcbc        dev-peer1-digitalproperty-network-0.7.0         "chaincode -peer.addr"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                                                     dev-peer1-digitalproperty-network-0.7.0
ebdaa8cb6e17        dev-peer0-digitalproperty-network-0.7.0         "chaincode -peer.addr"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                                                     dev-peer0-digitalproperty-network-0.7.0
71d6fe2731a5        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha      "peer node start --pe"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:7056->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7058->7053/tcp   peer1
24302fa77160        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha      "peer node start --pe"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0
fc0cb6a66977        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-ser"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca_peerOrg1
0750ca58d06f        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha   "orderer"                About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a HLF 1.0.0-alpha fabric, but when you started the rest server you specified defaultProfile which is a profile for hlf v0.6. When you deployed the digitalproperty-network you specified a profile hlfv1 (which is created for you when you follow the quickstart guide) which is the profile you need to use when you start the rest server.

Comment: Yep! Thanks! I have change the profie but no w I get this error: `calmadmin@localhost:~/composer-sample-applications-hlfv1/packages/getting-started$  composer-rest-server -p hlfv1 -n digitalproper               ty-network -i admin -s DJY27pEnl16d -N always
Discovering types from business network definition ...
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Connect Failed
    at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/gr               pc/src/node/src/client.js:201:19)
    at Cli `

Comment: enrollmentId and secret are also different for hlfv1.0.0-alpha they are currently admin and adminpw respectively, but the error you have there looks like it is having trouble communicating with your fabric, so need to check it is still running.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I know secret value for adminpw?

Comment: The enrollment id "admin" and it's enrollment secret "adminpw" is a default defined by the docker-compose file used to start all the fabric v1 containers. 
command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/peerOrg1-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/d8a5b3cac1b821f6e4b487ceaf1fd239cdcfc310894150908b90f05e9179556a_sk -b admin:adminpw' -d